# GANs: Should Generator update weights when Discriminator says false continuously

Tags: machine-learning, generative-adversarial-networks, generative-model, generator, discriminator

My GANs is like this:

- Train an autoencoder (VAE), get the decoder part and use as Generator
- Train Discriminator

After training, do the generation in these steps:

- Call Generator to generate an image
- Call the Discriminator to classify the image to see whether it's acceptable

The problem is that the Discriminator says 'false' a lot, which means the generated image is not useful.

How should the Generator change (update weights) when Discriminator doesn't accept its generated image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should train both discriminator D and generator G simultaneously.

Depending on the metric that you use as the target for your model, you may encounter a Vanishing gradient problem. It can happen when you implement original loss (i.e. JS-divergence). In that case D can become overconfident regarding fake samples and won't provide any useful feedback to the G. To find out if training fell into this problem, you should plot D and G loss. It will look as follows:

[image]

The original GAN has a lot of problems, that's why I suggest you to use Wasserstein metric. More information you can find in [WGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07875.pdf)

Here you can find more information about GAN problems:

- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.08994.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00140.pdf